# Rewriting URL: domain/folder/file.pdf to domain/folder

Tags: apache

I need to rewrite URL: domain/folder/file.pdf to domain/folder
web.telekom.sk/andy/katalog2013.pdf   to web.telekom.sk/andy

What rewrite rule should i use?

Comment: What is your aim?  To only allow people to list the files, but never download them?

Comment: My aim is to shorten the url. I want people to be able to view/download the pdf file but with the url web.telekom.sk/andy